# make custom validation in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i new in laravel i trying to make custom validation rule  to validate name of brand  i make this rule and worked normally :-

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //prepare data for validation
    request()->validate([
        'name'  => [
            'required',
            'min:2', // validate english name is exist before
            **function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                $englishname=Brand::where(['name'=>$value,'deleted'=>1 ])->first();
                if(false !=$englishname) {
                    $fail('Opps '.$attribute.' Is Exist Before.');
                }**
            },
        ],

    ],[],[
        "name"=>"Brand Name",
    ]);
```

validate name success  and no problem  but my real problem is  how  link id of brand in case of edit data  to make this function

```
**$englishname=Brand::where(['name'=>$value,'deleted'=>1,'id'=>$id ])->first()**
```

how to right function in validator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->validate($request,[
    'name'=>['required',Rule::unique('brands')->where('deleted_at',1)],
]);
```

## Note : please import Rule at top.

How to update existing current name ?

Code Below :

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
       'name'=>['required',Rule::unique('brands')->ignore($id)],
    ]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you try to make brand name unique, so you can try this:

```
request()->validate([
        'name'  => 'required|unique:<table name>,name'
 ]);
```

Comment: i wnt to add two condition deletede =0 and id !=id number from url

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom validate and notification

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
       'name'=>['required',Rule::unique('brands')->ignore($id)],
    ],
    [
       'required'=>'This field is required',
    ]);
 }
```